# How can I detect if an online backup service is doing IP-based throttling?

Tags: networking, speed, throttling, online-backup, online-storage

I live on a campus in the US and I am trying to understand why my upload speed to the  online backup service [Backblaze](http://www.backblaze.com/) on area Y of the campus is 10 times slower than on area X of the campus (20000 vs 2000 kpbs as you can see in the details below).

Area X on campus (Ethernet):

- Backblaze speedtest: Download Speed: 48764 kbps (6095.5 KB/sec transfer rate); Upload Speed: 25035 kbps (3129.4 KB/sec transfer rate)
- speedtest.net speed test: Download Speed: 82460 kbps; Upload Speed: 71640 kbps
- Backblaze actual upload speed using the client: around **20000 kbps**

Area Y on campus (Ethernet):

- Backblaze speedtest: Download Speed: 50500 kbps (6312.5 KB/sec transfer rate); Upload Speed: 3249 kbps (406.1 KB/sec transfer rate)
- speedtest.net speed test: Download Speed: 94790 kbps; Upload Speed: 50880 kbps
- Backblaze actual upload speed using the client: around **2000 kbps**

I have similar results for wifi but I think that's enough details.

The network administrator suspects that Backblaze is doing IP-based throttling. This surprised me as

- the Ethernet's IP is pretty similar between area X and Y
- the Wifi's IP is pretty similar between area X and Y
- I don't see what Backblaze would target area Y and not Y, since both are on the same campus. Also Backblaze vehemently denies doing any IP-based throttling, and I couldn't find anyone complaining about it.

My feeling is that area Y "as well connected" as X to the outer Internet, but most of the web services work fine, which gives credit to my network administrator's explanation.

Hence my question: is there any way to detect whether an online backup service is doing IP-based throttling, beyond comparing the upload speed with different IPs?

---

Some more details:

- All tests where carried out using the same laptop.
- I disabled the throttling in the Backblaze client's options.

Comment: I haven't found a solution so far.

Comment: But I'm still interested if someone has any idea.